# allowing faster recovery?

Tags: grammar

Source: Pediatric Surgery and Medicine for Hostile Environments​

> This environment decreases concussive forces on joints, allowing faster recovery.​

Could we also write this sentence as:

> Because / As a result of this environment decreases concussive forces on joints, faster recovery is allowed.

is it grammatically correct?

Comment: You could use "Because", but not "As a result of this". It doesn't work here. If you want to use "As a result of this" you would need to change the construction.  "This environment decreases concussive forces on joints, and as a result of this, faster recovery is allowed".

Comment: I don't think the rephrasing works at all. Tacking ***...allowing X** [to happen]* on to the end of an utterance is a particular convention equivalent to ***...leading to X*** (or ***creating a situation which is conducive to X** [happening]*). Converting that to ***X is allowed*** doesn't really work, because that "active verb" construction implies *X is **permitted / given permission** to occur*. Which is contextually nonsense.

Comment: [Relevant usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=allowing+full+recovery%2Cfull+recovery+is+allowed%2Cfull+recovery+was+allowed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) Note that almost all of the relatively few results for ***full recovery is/was allowed*** really are for the "given permission / accepted as valid" senses. For example: *His **claim** against the Health Authority for loss of the chance of a full recovery **was allowed by the trial judge***.

Comment: Why change it? It's fine as it is. X allows Y is NOT Y is allowed by X here.

Answer (score 0):

It's structurally correct, but it no longer makes sense. The word 'allow' has a few different meanings, and they are used differently. By changing the grammar, you have changed the meaning.

In the original sentence, 'allow' means *to **make it possible** for something to be done or to happen*.

The way you have rewritten it is not idiomatic for this definition. That is how we would phrase something if we meant 'allow' in the sense of ***permitting** something to happen*.